# Can't git reset to branch?

Tags: git

On occasion I use `git reset`.  Usually it is to 'undo' one or more commits.  E.g., if I want to get back to my commit state from 2 ago, I `git reset HEAD~2`.  Leaving all the changes from `HEAD~2` to `HEAD` in the staging area / index.

Currently I have a fair amount of commits, ~15 that I have added since branch off of `branchA`.  Now on `branchB` what I want to do is to reset it back to `branchA` leaving all of the changes from `branchA` -> `branchB` in the staging area.  I basically want to re-add and commit these changes in a new way.

`git reset` seems to take a commit as an argument, i.e. `git reset HEAD`.  So if I do `git reset HEAD^`, then all the changes i made since one commit ago will show up modified/changed in the staging area.  So why then won't `git reset branchA` just set back my branch ~15 commits? can  a branch not be used as a substitute for a commit in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for a soft reset:

```
git reset --soft branchA     # or
git reset --soft <SHA-1>
```

where `<SHA-1>` is the hash of the HEAD commit of `branchA`.

This soft reset will move the HEAD pointer of `branchB` back to the HEAD commit of `branchA` in the same branch.  However, it will not touch the stage or the working directory of `branchB`.  In other words, the diff changes between `branchA` and `branchB` will be in the stage and you can again commit them as you want.

Note that this is one way to squash a series of commits.  Another way to achieve what you want would be an interactive rebase, which however would be a bit more work.

**Update:**

The error `fatal: ambiguous argument 'branchA': both revision and filename` means that you have, in addition to a branch named `branchA`, also a folder or file named `branchA`.  To tell Git to use the branch and not the file/folder, use the following:

```
git reset --soft branchA --
```

Comment: yes, i am vaguely aware that what i'm doing is rebase-like.  but i think in my case i just want to commit as needed as the current set of commits have almost no value whatever with names like "SAVE" and "SAVE_STUFF".  but  the main thing i get from your response is that i cant use `branchA` but must first retrieve its `<SHA-1>` hash and use that as the argument to `reset`?

Comment: @AlexBollbach No you're right, resetting to the branch name should also work.

Comment: it doesn't, i get
`fatal: ambiguous argument 'branchA': both revision and filename`

Comment: Use this: `git reset --soft branchA --`